# How can protected property of a class be visible from a static method in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, visibility

I understand OOP. What I understand so far is that private and protected cannot be referenced from outside the class using $this->blah notation. If that is correct, how can the following code work?

```
<?php

 class test {
   protected $a = "b";

   public static function oo(){
     $instance = new static();
     echo $instance->a;
   }
 }

 test::oo();
```

Gives me an output of b! Now, how in Lord's name can that happen?

Comment: It think your main problem is this: outside the class is not the same as outside the instantiated object. There's the difference.

Comment: @Wrikken +1, my point exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP 5.3, a new feature called late static bindings was added – and this can help us get the polymorphic behavior that may be preferable in this situation. In simplest terms, late static bindings means that a call to a static function that is inherited will “bind” to the calling class at runtime. So, if we use late static binding it would mean that when we make a call to “test::oo();”, then the oo() function in the test class will be called.after that you return  $instance->a; static keyword allows the function to bind to the calling class at runtime.so if you use static then whatever  access modifier(private,public,protected)  you use it's just meaning less...

please  read this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php),[another](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/php-self-vs-static/)

Comment: **so if you use static then whatever access modifier(private,public,protected) you use it's just meaning less...** Magic! https://eval.in/226466 tested it and your explanation is correct! Thanks mate!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense whatsoever. From those links, "As  of PHP 5.3.0, PHP implements a feature called late static bindings which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance" - there is no inheritance here. The examples on those links have nothing to do with the OP's example. "this can help us get the polymorphic behavior" - what polymorphic behavior? This has nothing to do with "late static binding" - this is a simple OOP question.

Comment: i think at  first you have to know variable scope

Comment: This has nothing to do with scopes either. The scope of a variable is its lifetime. This isn't related to `a`'s lifetime. At all.

Comment: do you know when you call static then what is going on :)

Answer (score 4):

That happens because you're "presenting it" by `echo`'ing it. You can't reference it like this for example:

```
class test {
    private $a = 'b';

    function __construct() {
        echo 'instantiated';
    }
}

$test = new test();
echo $test->a; // This line won't work, since it's a private var.
```

It would give you an error message that looks like this:

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property test::$a

[**`Example (https://eval.in/226435)`**](https://eval.in/226435)

---

As I said before, you're accessing it from **within** the class itself, so you CAN view it. (That's the `$instance` you have there.) If you modify your code to use it like this:

```
 class test {
   protected $a = "b";

   public static function oo(){
     $instance = new static();
     return $instance;
   }
 }

echo test::oo()->a;
```

[**`Example of the above (https://eval.in/226439)`**](https://eval.in/226439)

You'll get that "private acess blah blah" error.

You're understanding the statement wrong. `"private and protected cannot be referenced from outside the class"` means that as the examples above show, you CAN NOT access the variables outside the class, but with your example, you're accessing it from INSIDE the class, which means they'll do as you require (`echo`'ing out as you did)

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Firstly static functions are non-aware of non-static class variables because the $this scope is not available, right? So, I gave it an instance in the form of $instance = new class(); Now, how can a private var of this $instance be accessible with $instance->var ??

Comment: You're accessing it from within the class itself, and since it is an instance of itself, it can easily access the `$a` variable. See the latest example (in my edit)

Comment: https://eval.in/226451 Check my update on the code, when I am feeding it an object of itself it still can't read the property.

Comment: Ha Ha your last edit is funny :P You said that if I do echo test::oo()->a; I will get that error?? Did you try this var_export(test::oo())?? It contains the property :D. Function result bodies are serialized and in PHP they are treated as arrays!

Comment: Haha good spot! I didn't think of `var_export()` none-the-less, I tried to explain you can't access the variable literal from outside the class.

Comment: Yeah.. but I got the answer, thanks a ton! After @Rajib I think it is all making sense. Now, I got what you're talking about! Thanks a ton mate!

Answer (score 2):

> What I understand so far is that private and protected cannot be referenced from outside the class

As follows, since `oo` is defined in the same type as `a`, `oo` has access to `a`.

Comment: Definitely not. OO doesn't have explicit access to a. How can that be? since oo is a static function, it cannot read non-static properties without being fed any instances of the class.

Comment: @ChristianM.Raymonds You're confusing "class" with "instance of a class". In your example, both methods are defined in the same class, though `a` will be called on an instance `$instance` of that class, and `oo` will be called without an instance (because it's static). Nevertheless, they are **defined** in the same class.

Comment: Now, I'm not familiar with PHP, but this behaviour is common to most (if not all) programming languages. Take a look at this trivial C# example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wxUAZA

Comment: Ok tell me something, are you saying that since the static function is defined in the class, it can read the class properties?

Comment: @ChristianM.Raymonds Yes. It doesn't matter what instance they belong to, or that they're being accessed from a static context, private members are visible to all members of the class in which they're declared.

Comment: What do you imply when you say "static context"?

Comment: @ChristianM.Raymonds I meant "from within a static method", for example, as in the code you posted. Not sure about PHP, but other languages have static constructors, static field initializers, static properties: all of these are considered static context. Sorry if that sounded confusing.

Comment: Static context: not bound to an instance of a class, but to the class itself. Then again, purists might argue the static context in OO is an abomination.

Comment: Gotcha brudda' Thanks a ton for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a very good question, and shouldn't be down-voted.

From what I understand, the reason why you can access a protected/private property from within a static method of the same class, is because "the implementation specific details are already known when inside this class". I rephrased this a little from what is documented on the official page on Visibility:

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is because the implementation specific details are already known when inside those objects.

This makes sense. Visibility access is meant to only expose things that are safe for the public to use. But if you already have access to the code of the Class you're using, then there is no point of preventing you to use what you already see. Hope that makes sense..